# Hide navbar on scroll - Tablet

Tags: jquery, css, hide

I'm using the following code to hide my navbar on scroll, but it doesn't seem to work on the iPad I'm testing on.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var previousScroll = 0,
headerOrgOffset = $('.hide-nav').height();

$('.sq-header-nav').height($('.hide-nav').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
    if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
        $('.sq-header-nav').slideUp();
    } else {
        $('.sq-header-nav').slideDown();
    }
}
previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IOS uses onscroll events

```
document.onscroll = function scroll() {
  // on scroll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Safari Developer Library Handling Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1). On iOS, `onscroll` event is not fired while you are scrolling but after the user stops panning (one or two fingers) and the page stops moving — after scrolling ends.

You can handle **while scrolling** with the `touchmove` event:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {/*handleMove*/}, false);
```

ref: [**MDN Touch Events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events).